# Change the colour of text as the user types hash tags

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, spannable

I am working on an application where the user can post content to a feed.  In my edit text (used for composing) the text colour is grey.  However when the user types a hash tag e.g. #help I need to colour that text black as they type, so when the user types '#' the text must be coloured black until they start a new word, then the text colour needs to revert to grey.

I have been trying using a text watcher and a spannable string to colour.

Here is what I have done with the textwatcher `onTextChanged`

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            //Remove Text watcher to prevent infinite look
            mTextField.removeTextChangedListener(contentFieldWatcher);
            String startChar = null;
                startChar = Character.toString(s.charAt(start));
                L.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "CHARACTER OF NEW WORD: " + startChar);


  if (startChar.equals("#")) {
                     tagCheck(s.toString().substring(start), start, start + count);
                }
            }
```

**tagCheck method**

```
private void tagCheck(String s, int start, int end) {
        mSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.black_colour)), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```

mSpannable is a Spannable.

The problem with this method is that '#' shows as startChar, however when the user types the next character, either symbol or letter, it then shows as startChar.  Where as if the user typed santa - 's' remains the startChar.  So the issue I'm facing his how to dynamically colour the text as the user types a hashtag.

So plain letters work correctly, however when you use a symbol it does not.  I hope the question has clarity..I've been looking at this for a few days and it's all getting hazy :)

Comment: I have written a custom EditText class in kotlin to achieve this, I hope it helps someone; https://stackoverflow.com/a/57481803/2522797

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried and found the ***soloution***

You can use following code

```
Spannable mspanable;
int hashTagIsComing = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    mspanable = edt.getText();

    edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String startChar = null;

            try{
                startChar = Character.toString(s.charAt(start));
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "CHARACTER OF NEW WORD: " + startChar);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                startChar = " ";
            }

                if (startChar.equals("#")) {
                     tagCheck(s.toString().substring(start), start, start + count);
                     hashTagIsComing++;
                }

                if(startChar.equals(" ")){
                    hashTagIsComing = 0;
                }

                if(hashTagIsComing != 0) {
                    tagCheck(s.toString().substring(start), start, start + count);
                    hashTagIsComing++;
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });



}


private void tagCheck(String s, int start, int end) {
    mspanable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.color)), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

Comment: Notice that you most make hashtag clear from inapropriate characters

Comment: there is an issue with auto suggest, if the user clicks on an auto suggestion, we lose the colouring

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve the behavior you are describing, it's just that I am setting the colored text on a separate TextView. See the screenshot and code below. I hope this helps

In afterTextChanged of the listener:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     editText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
     colorText(s.toString());
}
```

Method to find "#" characters and color text until first space:

```
private void colorText(String s) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(s);
        int position = 0;
        position = s.indexOf("#", position);
        while (position != -1) {
            colorSpannable(spannable, position, s.indexOf(" ", position + 1) != -1 ? s.indexOf(" ", position + 1) : s.length());
            position = s.indexOf("#", position + 1);
        }
        textView.setText(spannable);
    }
    editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
}
```

colorSpannable simply adds the color from index start to index end

```
private void colorSpannable(Spannable s, int start, int end){
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

[image]